# Question about how mongodb chooses indexes or $or queries

Tags: mongodb, indexing, aggregation

**Background**

I have a collection with the following schema:

```
{ appId, createdAt, lastSeen, lastHeard, deleted, ...otherFields }
```

and the following indexes:

```
{ appId: 1, deleted: 1, lastSeen: 1 }
{ appId: 1, deleted: 1, lastHeard: 1 }
{ appId: 1, createdAt: 1, deleted: 1 }
{ appId: 1, deleted: 1, createdAt: 1, lastSeen: 1, lastHeard: 1 }
```

In my application I have an aggregation:

```
 db.getCollection('client_users').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      deleted: false,
      appId: 'appid',
      $or: [
        { createdAt: { $gt: new Date('2020-10-19T17:00:00.000Z') } },
        { lastSeen: { $gt: new Date('2020-10-19T17:00:00.000Z') } },
        { lastHeard: { $gt: new Date('2020-10-19T17:00:00.000Z') } },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$geoLocation.city',
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      count: -1
    }
  }
]);
```

My intention was to use the first three indexes from the above for this aggregation, as I understand that the $or query is parsed into 3 separate queries. However, from the explain output, the winning plan uses the forth index (`{ appId: 1, deleted: 1, createdAt: 1, lastSeen: 1, lastHeard: 1 }` ) for the 2 last clauses:

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "FETCH",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "OR",
        "inputStages" : [
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "appId" : 1,
                    "createdAt" : 1,
                    "deleted" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "appId_1_createdAt_1_deleted_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "appId" : [],
                    "createdAt" : [],
                    "deleted" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "appId" : [
                        "[\"appid\", \"appid\"]"
                    ],
                    "createdAt" : [
                        "(new Date(1603126800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                    ],
                    "deleted" : [
                        "[false, false]"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "appId" : 1,
                    "deleted" : 1,
                    "createdAt" : 1,
                    "lastSeen" : 1,
                    "lastHeard" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "appId_1_deleted_1_createdAt_1_lastSeen_1_lastHeard_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "appId" : [],
                    "deleted" : [],
                    "createdAt" : [],
                    "lastSeen" : [],
                    "lastHeard" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "appId" : [
                        "[\"appid\", \"appid\"]"
                    ],
                    "deleted" : [
                        "[false, false]"
                    ],
                    "createdAt" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "lastSeen" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "lastHeard" : [
                        "(new Date(1603126800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "appId" : 1,
                    "deleted" : 1,
                    "createdAt" : 1,
                    "lastSeen" : 1,
                    "lastHeard" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "appId_1_deleted_1_createdAt_1_lastSeen_1_lastHeard_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "appId" : [],
                    "deleted" : [],
                    "createdAt" : [],
                    "lastSeen" : [],
                    "lastHeard" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "appId" : [
                        "[\"appid\", \"appid\"]"
                    ],
                    "deleted" : [
                        "[false, false]"
                    ],
                    "createdAt" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "lastSeen" : [
                        "(new Date(1603126800000), new Date(9223372036854775807)]"
                    ],
                    "lastHeard" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Which is not what I want. What's stranger is that when I try it with only 1 of the clauses, as in this $match stage:

```
$match: {
  deleted: false,
  appId: 'appid',
  lastSeen: {$gt: new Date('2020-10-19T17:00:00.000Z') },
}
```

It uses the correct index (`{ appId: 1, deleted: 1, lastSeen: 1 }`). I know this from the explain output and from timing the actual aggregation. Specifically, running it with no hint or with `hint: appId_1_deleted_1_lastSeen_1` takes three times shorter than with `hint: appId_1_deleted_1_createdAt_1_lastSeen_1_lastHeard_1`. This makes me very confused about how mongodb chooses the index.

Can someone explain to me what could have been the reason for this behavior? Is there a way for me to force mongodb to use the indexes I want in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was precisely because of the $or query. Mongodb chooses the query plan by letting them do a small race against each other. The more inefficient plan luckily won because the first $or clause took care of everything (remember it was $or so only 1 clause is enough). I fixed this by dropping the forth index.